# Cannot push to GitHub after installing tensorflow

Tags: python, git, tensorflow, github

I just ran `pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl` in my virtual environment `env` and tried to push it to my github repository. I got the following error:

```
remote: error: Trace: 90d476c4b164da6a6760e99c35acdb468039d7f953530ddff65f3657e1628a08
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so is 149.44 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/arielCheng218/cubism.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/arielCheng218/cubism.git'
```

How do I fix this and push the folder to my remote?
I am running this on Mac. Python version is 3.8.2 (64-bit).

Comment: It failed to push because of large files, you can see more in https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/configuring-git-large-file-storage

Comment: Is there any way to avoid LFS? Or do all tensorflow projects that are on github use it? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remote%3A+error%3A+GH001%3A+Large+files+detected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't commit your virtual environment `env/` at all, as it can be created from any requirements file, i.e `requirements.txt`.

Instead, add `env/` to your `.gitignore` file, or create one if it doesn't exist. Try to use a `.gitignore` template [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Python.gitignore) and edit it to your usage.